# Best way to get distance between two points in java?

Tags: java, distance

The user has to select two different points in two JComboBoxes, after selecting them, the program needs to get the distance between the two points selected.I can get the input from the ComboBoxes, but i need to calculate the distance between them, i tried using latitude and longitude, but i need to do that for every possible scenario( say 15 different points ). Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you share what you're tried so far, and where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: @Commongrate are your points far enough apart that you need to use spherical trigonometry?  If so, this question is not a duplicate and should be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some simple geometry using the pythagorean theorem, then you can just loop through the 15 different points and run the math for them all.

```
distance = sqrt(x*x+y*y)
```

In your case `x` and `y` are the delta between your 2 points (`x1-x2`, `y1-y2`)

```
double dx = pt1.x-pt2.x;
double dy = pt1.y-pt2.y;

double distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
```

http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php

Comment: Sorry, I understand the math portions, the thing that i don't understand is how to compare one point with the other 15 different times.

Comment: @Commongrate if you can post some of the code you are strugging with it will be easier to help. ATM im not sure and i think most people dont know what your points look like or what your doing with the comparing

Comment: @ ug_ Ok nvm what i said, can you tell me about the formula above and if it gives a value in radians or degrees?

Comment: @Commongrate Neither radians or degrees, it gives you a length. You should read about the formula and how to use it.

Comment: @ ug_ will do, thanks for the help.